# How to traverse mysql rows and build a route, to work out distance between an origin and destination row?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm looking for some ideas and suggestions, on the best way to work out a route, between two given points using PHP and a mysql database.

A user would input their starting location and a finishing location (these locations are defined in a MySQL table, and used in the route taken) , and the result would give the distance, in miles and the route taken.

The data, railway stations along a railway line.

I am thinking of rows in a database which lists mini routes for example, in one column, we'd have location 1 and in a second column we'd have location 2 - and in a third column, the distance between the 2. There would presumably be multiple entries for location 1 or 2 when a station branches off in 2 different directions and has 2 different next-station records.

So then when a user comes to enter their origin and destination, it would work out the route, and then traverse the mysql rows all the way to the row which has the end point, calculating the mileage along the way.

Would anyone have any ideas how I should approach this task, getting php using MySQL to use the two endpoints and work out a route between the two?

Because railway lines have curves etc it isn't possible to just use longitude and latitude and work it out on a map route planner.

Any starting tips or ideas would be welcome.

Comment: I think your approach is a valid one.

Comment: ...but note that this is 'np complete' class of problem, so not the kind of thing that an RDBMS is naturally geared towards. That said, for a smallish data set, you should be fine.